# Caching external web resources in AngularJS Cordova app

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I'm maintaining a AngularJS cordova app. In our app, sometimes we need to open an external web page. And in this case, we use

```
window.open('https://stackoverflow.com', '_blank');
```

to open this web page.

This way stills working fine until the external web page is fat enough. For now, users need to waits 8-10s to fully load this external page. (The external page was developed by Angular 2+ with service worker).

We know that it takes time to load Angular2+ app for the first time we load this page. But in the second time, it cached web resources and the time to load the page is reduce a lot.
However, when we open a page (using window.open), it considers this is the first time we load this external page is the first time loading. And when I open it from the second, we need to fully reload it again (and each time, the user needs to wait for 8-10s).

My question is: are there anyways to cache the external web resources so that when users open it from the second time, they don't need to wait too long as the first time they do?